# Eclipse doesn't recognize import

Tags: eclipse, import

I've been trying to import a very simple project I've started on a differnt laptop but for some reson the project now is full of errors.
Eclipse does not recognize imports being made and thus refuse to recognize simple classes as ActionBarActivity and methods like onCreate.

```
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Button bEnter=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bEnter);
            Button bSignup=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bSignup);
            bEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String toastText="It's Working!!!";
                    int toastDuration=Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastText, toastDuration);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
        }


    }

}
```

What am I missing here??

Answer (score 1):

What errors are you getting ?

Trick1:

If the appcompat_v7 project(library) is causing the problem, remove it from the project properties, then perform the following steps.
1) Right click on the main.
2) Hover over Android Tools.
3) Click 'Add Support Library'.

It will download the required library and the clean the project. It should work.
if doesn't work, let me know.

Trick2: Update to the latest Revisions ( Tools and SDKs using SDK manager)

Happy Coding.

Comment: First of all thanks.I've been trying to do Trick1, but unfortunatly there are more errors now.. 
I've also downloaded everything needed from the SDK manager..